# What does "to pick someone's cherry" mean?

Tags: meaning, offensive-language, minced-oaths

Does it strictly refer to taking someone's virginity, or does it express sexual intercourse in general?

Answer (score 12):

Nobody "picks" anybody's cherry. Cherries are "popped" and *cherry* in this case refers to hymen.

To "pop one's cherry" in a non-sexual way is to do a thing for the first time.

[Cherry-picking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking_%28fallacy%29) is something else altogether.

Comment: Which means you engage in cherry picking if you choose only the rules you like in a set of rules when you are supposed to use all the rules...

Comment: Cherry picking is also used in sports for someone who puts forth almost no defensive effort, relying on teammates to perform the defense and make a favorable play (like stealing the ball) but instead positioning themselves for the easy offensive play. It's typically combated by rules like "off-sides."

Comment: It's not just the hymen. *Popping one's cherry* can also refer to anal intercourse.

Answer (score 2):

From the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> **cherry** (noun) 4. [in sing.] [vulgar, slang] the hymen, as representing a woman's virginity.